# Container for classes, with cv-qualifier and reference preserved?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am relatively new to TMP in c++. **I was wondering if there is a way to implement a container for *classes*(not its instances!) in c++**(17, without boost or c++20, preferrably.)

Below is what I am looking for:

```
int integer = 0xDEADBEEF;
std::string hello ("hello");
boost::any c (integer);
const int c_deadbeef = integer;
int& cr_deadbeef (integer);

using oneClassContainer = decltype( makeClassContainer(integer, hello, c, c_deadbeef, cr_deadbeef) );
// classContainer<int, std::string, boost::any, const int, int&>

using anotherClassContainer = classContainer<int, const int&, const int>;

// anotherClassContainer is passed to a different function.
// in that function:
getType<anotherClassContainer,0> anotherInt = 3; //int
getType<anotherClassContainer,1> constIntRef (anotherInt); //const int&
getType<anotherClassContainer,2> constIntRef= 3; //const int
```

**I would also like the constness to be preserved when classContainer is created using `makeClassContainer` function arguments.** For example, `const int b=3;` and then a`make_tuple(b,1)` call returns a `tuple<int,int>` - the `const` went missing, and therefore using `make_tuple`, in any way, is not an option here. (*In fact, if we could somehow keep the `const` and `volatile` qualifications in `make_tuple`, this would be the perfect solution*)

**So to summarize, my question is if the following is possible to implement:**

- **a structure that contains *classes* (not necessarily their instantiations), with**

  - **ability to accurately pick up cv-qualification and r/lval reference qualification from declared variables**
  - **ability to *return* types in some way so that they may be used in declarations**
  - **ability to be passed around to different contexts** (easily achievable, but nonetheless an important condition)

And I would be elated to receive an answer. Thank you!

Comment: In some OO languages, the class definition is itself an object, which acts as a factory that produces instances.  C++ is not like that:  the class is not an object, it is not an instance of some meta-class.  At best you could have classes be registered with a class container, and have the class static functions and member functions interact with the class container for your purposes (logging, total objects created, current live object count, whatever).  But such instrumentation will be intrusive.

Comment: From function call, `integer` and `cr_deadbeef` are both lvalue. There is [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) which can be used to allow reference addition.

Comment: Else MACRO, where you can use `decltype(integer)` (`int`) versus `decltype(cr_deadbeef)` (`int&`).

Comment: `getType<anotherClassContainer,0>` is basically [`std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distinguish `integer` and `cr_deadbeef` in a call site, so your desired syntax of `decltype( makeClassContainer(integer, hello, c, c_deadbeef, cr_deadbeef) )` is a non-starter. You would have to apply `decltype` earlier.

Either directly

```
using my_type_1 = std::tuple<decltype(integer), decltype(hello), decltype(c), decltype(c_deadbeef), decltype(cr_deadbeef)>;
```

Or through a macro

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define ADD_DECLTYPE(a, b, x) decltype(x)
#define MAKE_TYPE_LIST(...) std::tuple< BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM( BOOST_PP_SEQ_TO_TUPLE( BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM( ADD_DECLTYPE, 0, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__) ) ) ) >
using my_type_2 = MAKE_TYPE_LIST(integer, hello, c, c_deadbeef, cr_deadbeef);
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0314f168923e084)